# Trouble graphing two series' on python histogram

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a histogram from different columns of an imported CSV file (data_dict). I am trying to solve the question below- the axis appear when I type the below code, however, the plots do not. How would I go about plotting these? Many thanks.

**Question**

Write your code to plot a histogram of number of accidents by age for females and males separately. Use 10-year bins. Plot both distributions on the same plot.

```
gender1 = np.array(data_dict['Gender'])
age1 = np.array(data_dict['Age'])

age_females = age1[np.where(gender1 == 'Female')]
age_males = age1[np.where(gender1 == 'Male')]


plt.hist(age_males,label='Males',alpha=0.5)
plt.hist(age_females,label='Females',alpha=0.5)
plt.legend()
plt.title('Histogram of Accidents by Age and Genders')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Accidents')
plt.xticks(ticks=np.arange(10,110,step=10),labels=(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100))
print
```

Answer (score 0):

To me the code looks all right. I ran the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([i for i in range(50)])
b = np.array([i for i in range(50,100)])
plt.hist(a,label='Males',alpha=0.5)
plt.hist(b,label='Females',alpha=0.5)
plt.legend()
plt.title('Histogram of Accidents by Age and Genders')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Accidents')
plt.xticks(ticks=np.arange(10,110,step=10),labels=(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100))
plt.show()
```

and got this plot:

[image]

Can you reproduce this picture and if so, are you sure your age_-arrays contain the required data?

EDIT based on comment:
Well, that depends on what format your dictionary actually contains. Try to get your arrays into this format:

```
gender1 = np.array(['male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female']) 
age1 = np.array([22,25,23,40,60]) 

age_females = age1[np.where(gender1=='female')] 
age_males = age1[np.where(gender1=='male')]
```

While there are more elegant ways to do the indexing, this should work if you get whatever comes out of the dictionary to this array form.

Comment: I need to find the age of males and females- i.e. age from (data_dict['Age']) where the gender from (data_dict['Gender']) is male and then also where the gender from (data_dict['Gender']) is female. Currently, I cannot get the seperate age values for male and female